# Request to MongoDB, data aggregation and further data writing to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to read data from the MongoDB collection, aggregate it with Node.js and then write to new collections based on obtained from the aggregation fields.

The code works and creates new 168 collections (for each weekday and hour) with the correct input.

However, a terminal returns the following error statements

- (node:15124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Has anyone ideas what is wrong with the code ?

```
MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {

if (err) throw err;

var dbo = db.db("pspDB");
dbo.collection("Collection1").aggregate(
    [{ $match: { status: "SETTLED" } },

    {
        $project:
        {
            TimeStart: "$creationDate",
            startMonth: { $month: "$creationDate" },
            startDay: { $dayOfMonth: "$creationDate" },
            startHour: { $hour: "$creationDate" },
            startDayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$creationDate" },
            startWeek: { $week: "$creationDate" },
            price: "$price"
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Collection2",
            localField: "TimeStart",
            foreignField: "TimeStart",
            as: "weekAndHour"
        }
    },


    {
        $unwind: "$weekAndHour"
    },

    {
        $unwind: "$weekAndHour.Utilization"
    },

    {
        $project:
        {   
            TimeStart: 1,
            startMonth: 1,
            startDay: 1,
            startHour: 1,
            startDayOfWeek: 1,
            startWeek: 1,
            price: 1,
            utilisation: "$weekAndHour.Utilization"
        }
    }



    ]).toArray(async function (err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        // Creating collections for all weekdays and hours (168 in total) for aggregation purposes

        for (var mk = 0; mk <= 7; mk++) { 

            for (var ik = 0; ik < 24; ik++) {

                var picked = lodash.filter(result, { 'startHour': ik, 'startDayOfWeek': mk })

                console.log(picked)

                var name = "WEEKDAY" + mk + "H" + ik
                console.log(name)


                dbo.collection(name).insertMany(picked)


            }
        }


    })


   })
```